# what does secant mean in mathematics?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I need your help.

pleas I need some one to explain for me what does ***secant***  mean in mathematics?

Clear example with images would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an image in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_line)

Answer (score 2):

In geometry, a secant is **a line that intersects a circle twice**.

[image: Secant]

In calculus, the secant line is **a line that (locally) intersects a curve twice**. It is used to approximate the slope within a particular interval.

[image: Derivative with secant and tangent]

In the image, the line that intersects twice is called the secant line, the line tangent to a point is the tangent line.

This is where the geometric definition of the derivative comes from.

The slope of the secant line (intersecting the curve at $(x,f(x))$ and at $(x+h,f(x+h)$) as $h\to0$ is the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x,f(x))$ (formula: $m=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$).